# Override or overload AutoComplete Append rule

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I have a textbox which sends some commands to an instrument. I added the AutoComplete feature to this textbox and things are going easier now.

What I am thinking to improve this, is to add a possibility that when user enters a command (just a text) while AutoComplete finds a match it also shows a description for that command.

At the moment, I have all the AutoComplete strings in a text file and I load it when the application starts. The textfile contains lines like this:

```
*IDN?   #Query the instrument for identification
*RST    #Resets the instrument
```

So what is happening in my application is that because AutoComplete is in `SuggestAppend` mode, the description of command also gets into the textbox (this will be the same if I only put it in `Suggest` mode)

What I need to know is how to force the AutoComplete to append the text while its

1. Does not add any text starting from `#` char while appending the suggested text
2. Trim() the text to avoid that spaces you see in the textfile source

**UPDATE 1**
Ok, I think the only way is to make a new class and inherit from `AutoCompleteStringCollection` And in this new class, somehow override the reponsible method for returning (appending) suggested text. I really have no idea what should I do:

```
class MyAutoCompleteCollection : AutoCompleteStringCollection 
{
    //How to override Get function of AutoCompleteStringCollection class?
    //It is not avilable to override :(
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I found out that methods in `AutoCompleteStringCollection`are not overridable. I am looking for a way to change the way the `[]` method (to be honest I do not know what to call it!) works. Does someone have any idea about this?

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
When the text without #DESC  goes into the textbox, I have a event handler for KeyDown which will transfer the command to the instrument.

Comment: Can you post your existing code of handling the autocompletion? It's easier to suggest code solution by looking at code.

Comment: Maybe you should use `.Remove(base.Text.LastIndexOf('#'), base.Text.Length - 1).Trim();` in the moment that you load the file.

Comment: No! the whole idea is to display the text after # inside the autocomplete box! I just want it to does not go inside my text box.

Comment: [] is called an Indexer. It's called an Indexer because you put an index in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to battle the autocomplete functionality that Microsoft has implemented, I strongly suggest that you use a multi-column combobox instead.

All of the ones that we have used support auto-completion, so you can store your command in the first column and have it be your value and then store your description in the second column.

There are a tremendous number of controls available for purchase (Infragistics, Intersoft, Syncfusion, etc) and you can probably find free or self-built versions on various sites such as CodeProject.

Going this route should save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Staying with using the `SuggestAppend` method and loading your text file as a Custom Source for the Auto Complete feature of the TextBox.

You could use the `Leave` event of the TextBox to remove all text after # and trim the result:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("#")).Trim();
}
```

This way the description stays in the auto complete list, but as soon as you tab out or leave the textbox, only the command remains.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I am sorry that I forgot to mention I also have a KeyDown event for text box which on Enter key will pass the command to the instrument. That also should be taken care of (I think it will be the same as your method...) I gonna try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link which has the complete example for Autocomplete

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/chff42zw
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your update nr. 2: 
The [] is actually an Index Property.

Your class implements an collection. You can get item at index X by using the collowing code:

```
var thirdItem = myAutoCompleteCollectionInstance[3];
```

Index properties can be created manually by using the code below, which you can use to customize the order by returning the items you want at the specified indexes.

```
 public string this[int index] {get ...} {set...}
```

Answer (score -1):

The AutoComplete property of Textbox is set SuggestAppend which means it adds both the text and the description. So you need to set AutoComplete property of Textbox to "Suggest" value only.

According to MSDN the Autocomplete property can take four enum values namely

The following are the values of AutoCompleteMode:

```
Append : Appends the remainder of the most likely candidate string to the existing characters, highlighting the appended characters.

Suggest : Displays the auxiliary drop-down list associated with the edit control. This drop-down is populated with one or more suggested completion strings.

SuggestAppend : Appends both Suggest and Append options.

None : Disables automatic completion. This is the default.
```

Try these values instead of subclassing the AutoCompleteStringCollection.

Comment: Hmmm...even in Suggest mode, if user press enter, the selected suggested string will get into the textbox, no difference compared to SuggestAppend.

Comment: I think there is some mistyping of code. Probably you need to verify from the beginning. I have pasted the link which has complete example you can use it as a reference and cross verify it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/chff42zw